# Как разместить две карусели на яваскрипт на одной странице?

Tags: javascript

Для пролистывания блоков использую карусель [jCarousel Lite](http://www.gmarwaha.com/jquery/jcarousellite/).
Как эту карусель вставить на страницу два раза?
Вставляю два раза, и при нажатии на кнопки пролистывания проматываются сразу две карусели.

**UPD:** Вопрос больше не актуален. Нужно было просто поменять классы дива и кнопок переключения во второй карусели. Яваскрипт трогать не надо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте [jcarousel](http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/). Проверено. Две карусели работают независимо друг от друга.

Comment: Да у меня уже выше описанная стоит. Не хочется менять. А есть где дэмку посмотреть?